# MySQL - join/group concat returning too many items

Tags: mysql, sql, string, pivot, aggregate-functions

I've got a simple query which brings up wins, draws and losses in a head-to-head matches table.

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN score_w > score_m THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS wins_w,
    SUM(CASE WHEN score_m > score_w THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS wins_m,
    SUM(CASE WHEN score_w = score_m THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS draws
FROM 6dos7me3xn8
```

All is well. I get a single row, with the data I need as columns.

Now I want to also pull out a group concat'd list of the most recent **three** match dates. I tried:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN mn.score_w, 0) > mn.score_m THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS wins_w,
    SUM(CASE WHEN mn.score_m > mn.score_w THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS wins_m,
    SUM(CASE WHEN mn.score_w = mn.score_m THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS draws,
    GROUP_CONCAT(jn.date) AS recent
FROM 6dos7me3xn8 mn
JOIN (SELECT date FROM 6dos7me3xn8 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3) jn
```

...but the `LIMIT` is having no effect, seemingly - I get **all** of the dates group concat'd, not just 3.

I also tried removing the `JOIN` and replacing the `GROUP_CONCAT` with

```
GROUP_CONCAT((SELECT date FROM 6dos7me3xn8 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3)) AS recent
```

...but that errors with 'Subquery returns more than 1 row.'

I'm sure it's something simple, but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I note that you've asked the very highest rated contributor to provide a demonstration. No doubt they will be happy to oblige but, personally, I think that's the wrong approach. I think *you* should provide the model.

Comment: You think asking for clarification on an answer is "the wrong approach"? So if someone doesn't understand an answer, they're not supposed to seek clarification? The model is, I would argue, entirely unimportant to understanding and answering my question (again, as evidenced by the three people who did.)

Comment: That's fine. I disagree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do this with window functions:

```
select
    sum(score_w > score_m) as wins_w,
    sum(score_m > score_w) as wins_m,
    sum(score_w = score_m) as draws,
    group_concat(case when rn <= 3 then date end) as recent
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(order by date desc) rn
    from `6dos7me3xn8` t
) t
```

The subquery ranks records by descending date; we can then use that information in the outer query. Note that you don't need the `case` expressions: MySQL evaluates true/false conditions as 1/0 in numeric contet.

In earlier versions, the simpler approach is probably a row-limiting subquery:

```
select
    sum(score_w > score_m) as wins_w,
    sum(score_m > score_w) as wins_m,
    sum(score_w = score_m) as draws,
    (select group_concat(date) from (select date from `6dos7me3xn8` order by date desc limit 3) t) as recent
from `6dos7me3xn8`
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks (in particular for the tip on no need for `CASE` / `COLAESCE`). Only thing was I got an error saying every derived table needed an alias (with your second snippet). I added the alias and all is well.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a `cross join`.  TO get the most recent three dates, you can use:

```
FROM (SELECT mn.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY date desc) as seqnum
      FROM 6dos7me3xn8 mn
     ) mn
WHERE seqnum <= 3
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure where that should fit into my overall query. Would you mind demonstrating? Would the overall stats (the part that's working) still take into account all matches, not just the latest 3?

Answer (score 1):

You have no `ON` clause to specify the relationship between the subquery and the table you're joining it to. So you get a full cross product.

You also need `ORDER BY` to make it return the 3 most recent dates, not any 3 dates.

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN mn.score_w, 0) > mn.score_m THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS wins_w,
    SUM(CASE WHEN mn.score_m > mn.score_w THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS wins_m,
    SUM(CASE WHEN mn.score_w = mn.score_m THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS draws,
    GROUP_CONCAT(jn.date) AS recent
FROM 6dos7me3xn8 mn
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT date 
    FROM 6dos7me3xn8 
    ORDER BY date DESC
    LIMIT 3
) jn ON jn.date = mn.date
```

Comment: Thanks, I will study your answer. The `ORDER BY` omission was just some over-zealous SO pruning - it's there in the real query.